# Program error while using python subprocess.call() function

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to open a program while I'm in a python script using the subprocess.call() function, It opens the program but for some reason the program doesn't allows that and just throw an "Unhandaled exception" error, I know the problem is probably in the program so there may be any other command that will open a program, fill some fields and press "Submit?"

Thanks!

**Edit:** I've no code to post..

```
str = 'd:\Softwares\X.exe'
subprocess.call(str)
```

I've also tried with:

```
subprocess.call(str,shell=True)
```

Comment: Paste the relevant code of the program you are trying to call.

Comment: Just code style — Don't call name variable `str`, and either write `'D:\\Softwares\\X.exe'` or `r'D:\Softwares\X.exe'` or `'D:/Softwares/X.exe'`.

Comment: You should be warned that subprocess.call isn't going to let you perform window-level operations like filling in fields and pushing buttons and the like in other programs.  That's an entirely different kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling another program the same way. If the problem persists, the problem is with your code. If it goes away, the problem is with the program.

I think changing to 'D:/Softwares/X.exe' or one of the other string formats will help because the '\' character is the escape character ... used for example to denote a new line '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

It probably works if you use forward-slashes (backslashes are escape symbols in Python). If it doesn't, write the first line like this:

```
str = r'd:\Softwares\X.exe'
```

The *r* tells Python that you are creating a raw string, so it will ignore escape symbols. More information at: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals